# How can I add together 2 timeseries that have unix timestamps if the unix timestamps don't align?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp, unix-timestamp, quantitative-finance

I have Orderbook update data for 2 different assets and the updates happen at different unix timestamps, so the timeseries are both of different length and have different indexes. How should I go about adding the 2 dataframes together in a way that it always uses the most recent data and gives me a new array that's the size of all unique timestamps of both?

Tried looping through the timestamp arrays of both assets and moving up in the index of one of the arrays if it's timestamp is bigger than the other at the current index of both but that doesn't work for some reason. Is that a valid approach?

Comment: Can you give us example of your data, and your desired output ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly ,You can concat dataframes and sort them by their timestamps.

```
btc_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['1672472284', 'btc'],
        ['1672472264', 'btc'],
        ['1672472244', 'btc'],
        ['1672472224', 'btc'],], 
    columns = ['time', 'pair']
)

eth_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['1672472283', 'eth'],
        ['1672472265', 'eth'],
        ['1672472244', 'eth'],
        ['1672472223', 'eth'],], 
    columns = ['time', 'pair']
)

concated_df = pd.concat([btc_df, eth_df]).sort_values('time')
concated_df

    time    pair
3   1672472223  eth
3   1672472224  btc
2   1672472244  btc
2   1672472244  eth
1   1672472264  btc
1   1672472265  eth
0   1672472283  eth
0   1672472284  btc
```